# Angular + Webpack [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template

Tags: angularjs, webpack

If anybody had a such problem please help.

I use `Angular` + `Webpack` and trying to require HTML files to my JS with `html-loader`.

At first I have required `html` file to my `directive`

```
var templateUrl = require('./test.html');
```

Then I do `webpack` command and webpack says everything is fine and bundle all file without any problem.

Then I have an ERROR (it's in my console):

```
[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: <div class="test">
<p>This is my TEST</p>
</div> (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

As I understand it's sees my html, but before this it's says that can't GET it(a template), why is that?

Request in the network

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:7773/portal/%3Cdiv%20class=%22test%22.....
```

For example success requires:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:7773/portal/dev/bundle.js
```

As I understand webpack looking it in some another place. How to fix it?

For info my full path:

```
/home/darthjs/Documents/****/src/public/portal/app/components/navtop/test.html
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `template: require('./test.html')` instead of `templateUrl`.
On your directives:

```
{ // directive definition object
  restrict: 'A',
  template: require('./file.html')
}
```

Comment: Ou my God! Seriously! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Should be `template: require('./file.html').default`. Had to google a lot to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading file contents and using it as URL. You should use [ngtemplate-loader](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader) (or any other similar loader) to get what you want – it will put file contents in Angular's template cache.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, I don't know why, but non of the html templates I can't install. I've just tried template-html-loader and ngtemplate-loader.